# Exponentially-weighted moving mean and standard deviation of an irregularly-spaced weighted time series

Tags: python, performance, numpy, statistics, vectorization

The following numpy/python function computes exponentially-weighted moving mean and standard deviation of an irregularly-spaced weighted time series. I want to make it faster by getting rid of the python loop and relying on numpy vectorization. However, while I can move some computation out of the loop, I'm unable to come up with a way to untangle the dependencies that exist between consecutive `mean` and `variance` values. Is it even possible?

I'd rather avoid Numba, Cython or the like.

```
import numpy as np


def ewm(values, time_steps, weights, decay_rate=0.01, variance_epsilon=1e-6):
    '''Compute exponentially-weighted moving mean and standard deviation of an
    irregularly-spaced weighted time series.
       
    :param values: 1D array of event values.
    :param time_steps: 1D array of floats. Each value indicates how much time
        has passed since the previous event (or the start of
        the series for the first event).
    :param weights: 1D array of floats. Each value indicates how much an event
        contributes to the moving mean and standard deviation.
    :param decay_rate: float. Describes how much influence of past events
        declines per unit of time.
    :param variance_epsilon: Added to variance for numerical stability when
        computing standard deviation.
    :returns: Tuple of two float arrays. The first is exponentially weighted
        moving means immediately after each event. The second is exponentially 
        weighted moving standard deviations immediately after each event.  
    '''

    momentum = 0.0
    mean = 0.0
    variance = 0.0

    means = np.empty_like(values)
    stds = np.empty_like(values)
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        retention = (1.0 - decay_rate) ** time_steps[i]

        new_momentum = momentum * retention + weights[i]

        means[i] = mean = \
            mean * (momentum / new_momentum) * retention + \
            values[i] * weights[i] / new_momentum

        deviation = values[i] - mean

        variance = \
            variance * (momentum / new_momentum) * retention + \
            np.square(deviation) * weights[i] / new_momentum

        momentum = new_momentum

        stds[i] = np.sqrt(variance + variance_epsilon)

    return means, stds
```

Sample usage:

```
means, stds = ewm(
    np.asarray([1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.]),
    np.asarray([1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1.]),
    np.asarray([1., 1., 1., 1., 5., 5., 1., 1., 1., 1.]),
)
# [1.         1.50251256 1.33219236 1.5037909  1.2192523
#  1.5028668  1.4681632  1.50314792 1.47179905 1.50307306]
print(means)

# [0.001      0.35266091 0.34585958 0.39006561 0.30556194 
#  0.38630063 0.39249905 0.40020053 0.40503148 0.41104515]
print(stds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple recursive (in the mathematical relation sense, not the computer science sense) expressions, notably on momentum, mean and variance. There is some minor vectorisation that can be done. I have tested this suggested code for correctness according to your provided examples. I've shown it to pull apart and illustrate what can be vectorised and what can't. I've also found `accumulate` to be a pain, because it seems to ignore the `identity` and `dtype` parameters.

Lo, there is hope: despite this looking as ugly as heck, in my testing it offers a ~180% speedup.

### Suggested code

Docstrings omitted for brevity.

```
from timeit import timeit

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng


def ewm_old(values, time_steps, weights, decay_rate=0.01, variance_epsilon=1e-6):
    momentum = 0.0
    mean = 0.0
    variance = 0.0

    means = np.empty_like(values)
    stds = np.empty_like(values)
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        retention = (1.0 - decay_rate) ** time_steps[i]

        new_momentum = momentum * retention + weights[i]

        means[i] = mean = \
            mean * (momentum / new_momentum) * retention + \
            values[i] * weights[i] / new_momentum

        deviation = values[i] - mean

        variance = \
            variance * (momentum / new_momentum) * retention + \
            np.square(deviation) * weights[i] / new_momentum

        momentum = new_momentum

        stds[i] = np.sqrt(variance + variance_epsilon)

    return means, stds


def ewm_new(
    values: np.ndarray,
    time_steps: np.ndarray,
    weights: np.ndarray,
    decay_rate: float = 0.01,
    variance_epsilon: float = 1e-6,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,
    np.ndarray,
]:
    def make_momentum(momentum: float, i: int) -> float:
        return momentum * retention[i-1] + weights[i-1]
    def make_means(mean: float, i: int) -> float:
        return mean*coefficients[i-1] + values[i-1]*offsets[i-1]
    def make_variances(variance: float, i: int) -> float:
        return variance*coefficients[i-1] + deviations[i-1]*offsets[i-1]

    retention = (1 - decay_rate)**time_steps
    momenta = np.frompyfunc(
        make_momentum, nin=2, nout=1, identity=0,
    ).accumulate(np.arange(len(values))).astype(np.float64)

    factors = momenta * retention / weights
    coefficients = factors / (factors + 1)
    offsets = 1 / (1 + factors)
    means = np.frompyfunc(
        make_means, nin=2, nout=1, identity=0,
    ).accumulate(np.arange(1+len(values)))[1:].astype(np.float64)

    deviations = (values - means)**2
    variances = np.frompyfunc(
        make_variances, nin=2, nout=1, identity=0,
    ).accumulate(np.arange(1+len(values)))[1:].astype(np.float64)

    stds = np.sqrt(variances + variance_epsilon)
    return means, stds


def test() -> None:
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    values, time_steps, weights = rand.random((3, 10))
    means, stds = ewm_new(values, time_steps, weights)

    assert np.allclose(
        means,
        np.array((
            0.63696169, 0.33792459, 0.09563421, 0.06077860, 0.28410923,
            0.38241663, 0.44761338, 0.51056811, 0.51504314, 0.56303342,
        )),
        rtol=0, atol=1e-6,
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        stds,
        np.array((
            0.00100000, 0.06149956, 0.05598960, 0.05115476, 0.29145246,
            0.34006516, 0.29895069, 0.28304818, 0.26340344, 0.27797243,
        )),
        rtol=0, atol=1e-6,
    )

    values     = np.array((1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), dtype=np.float64)
    time_steps = np.array((1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), dtype=np.float64)
    weights    = np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=np.float64)
    means, stds = ewm_new(values, time_steps, weights)

    assert np.allclose(
        means,
        (
            1.0000000,  1.50251256, 1.33219236, 1.50379090, 1.21925230,
            1.5028668,  1.46816320, 1.50314792, 1.47179905, 1.50307306,
        ),
        rtol=0, atol=1e-6,
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        stds,
        (
            0.00100000, 0.35266091, 0.34585958, 0.39006561, 0.30556194,
            0.38630063, 0.39249905, 0.40020053, 0.40503148, 0.41104515,
        ),
        rtol=0, atol=1e-6,
    )


def profile() -> None:
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)

    scale = np.round(10**np.linspace(0, 4, 150)).astype(int)
    times = []

    for n in scale:
        values, time_steps, weights = rand.random((3, n))

        for method in (ewm_old, ewm_new):
            t = timeit(lambda: method(values, time_steps, weights), number=1)
            times.append((method.__name__, n, t))

    df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=('method', 'n', 'time'))
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x='n', y='time', hue='method')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    profile()
```

[image: profile]